# Aggregation on FireStore/CloudDatastore. Use Cloud Functions onCreate/Update?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create an expense tracker and one of the things I want to find out is how much did I spend in each month per category.

How should I do this in FireStore/DataStore?

1. Pull down required data and do aggregation locally? Seems very slow?
2. Perform aggregation everytime a transaction is created/updated and save it in a table? But this may result in many invocations of the functions, which may be costly?

Is there a better way? Seems like 2 is currently the best option? But I wonder if theres anyway I can reduce costs?

I note that I may not need the aggregated data to be realtime, so is there a way to debounce the cloud function execution? Since I note that at times, I will batch insert a bunch of transactions. Wonder if theres a way to disable functions for certain queries and manually call them after the batch has finished for example?

Answer (score 4):

The two approaches you describe are indeed the most common.

The best approach mostly depends on the number of transactions you have. If you have few transactions, then it may be totally fine to do the aggregation on each client. But as you get more transactions, the overhead of downloading the data will become prohibitive and you're more likely to want to keep a running total in the database.

I'd normally recommend keeping the total up to date with any transaction. You can even do that with client-side code, by using transactions (to prevent multiple users overwriting each other's updates) and server-side security rules (to prevent malicious actors from writing an aggregate that doesn't match its transaction).

If you want to aggregate in batches, you'll want to run code periodically, either in a server you control, or in Cloud Functions.

There is nothing built into Cloud Functions to debounce document writes. You could probably keep a debounce counter in Firestore, but that would then be reading/writing a document on each transaction.

More reasonable seems to run a function on a timer, as described in this blog post and shown in this video. But you'll need to make sure your data structure in that case allows the code to detect what transactions it needs to aggregate.

One way to do this is to ensure the transactions can be ordered in some way, e.g. by giving them a `timestamp`, and having your aggregation code keep track (likely in the database) of the last timestamp it has aggregated already. Then whenever the aggregator runs, it:

1. reads the current aggregated value
2. queries the database for transactions that have been added since it last ran
3. loops over those transactions, updating the aggregated value
4. writes the aggregated value and the last timestamp back to the database in a transaction (to ensure either both are written, or neither is written)

Comment: Please share if this is still the best approach or there are any new methods for aggregation available now.